# Changing Iframe src in Ajax success call - Web server will Get source references twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a html page with iframe element and when I tried to set the iframe source after getting some information through ajax call, it will get multiple Get request for the source references from server.

**Iframe.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bigfile.js"></script> // 3MB Size
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="samplefile"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: my_url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#samplefile").attr("src", "data.html");
        }
        });     
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    Some Content    
</body>
</html>
```

**Screen Shot:**
[image]

As you can see the screen shot there are two jquery script Get request from data.html. How to avoid these unwanted Get Request from server?